# Why is my allocated buffer not the right size?

Tags: c++, file-io

I used the fread function and I am getting a buffer size 4 and a "Reading Error".

Why is my `buffer` not the `fileSize`?

Here is my code:

```
FILE *fp;
char* buffer;
fp = fopen("help.txt","r");
if (fp == NULL){
    fputs("Can't open Help file, Help.txt",stderr);
exit(1);
}
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long fileSize = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*fileSize);
if(buffer == NULL){
    fputs("Memory Allocation Error",stderr);
    exit(2);
}

size_t result = fread(buffer,1,fileSize,fp);
if(result != fileSize){
fputs("Reading error\n",stderr);
printf("File Size : %lu\n",fileSize);
printf("Result : %lu\n",result);
printf("Buffer Size : %u\n",sizeof(buffer));
exit(3);
}

fputs(buffer,stdout);

fclose(fp);
free (buffer);
```

This is the output when I run the program:

```
Reading error
File Size : 224
Result : 219
Buffer Size : 4
```

Comment: Try to open the file binary by adding a "b" -> `fopen("help.txt","rb");` I think you have there some invisible chars or something like that which destroys your calculation.

Comment: the "invisible chars" are system newlines being translated to C++ newlines, you lose a few bytes.  Opening in binary mode prevents that translation.

Comment: If you're using C++, why not read files the C++ way (with iostreams)?

Comment: because I was going over c and c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer is allocated correctly. The buffer size is calculated uslng `sizeof(char)*fileSize`, not `sizeof(buffer)`. You can test if the buffer was allocated or not by verifying if `buffer` is null. If it's not, then it successfully allocated the buffer with the size greater than or equal to the size you requested.

The problem is that you opened the file in text mode. Because of that, Windows will replace all the "\r\n" sequences in your file with "\n" as ANSI C requires. You can either accept this behavior or you can open your file in binary mode using `fp = fopen("help.txt","rb");` to read all the contents unaltered.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that just as you were typing. An alternative approach (if you don't want to read in binary mode) is to count the number of `\n`s in the resulting string and adjust the size accordingly when comparing.

Answer (score 5):

`buffer` is a `char*`. Pointers are 4 bytes in size (for a 32-bit system). So `sizeof(buffer)` will always print 4.

After you allocate a pointer with a certain size, the size of the memory block it points to is what you allocated it with. In this case, `sizeof(char)*fileSize`.

**Edit** Oh, to answer your *real* question, wasn't there a problem in Windows where ftell reports the size in bytes, counting every CRLF as 2 bytes. When you read this in a buffer, CRLFs are translated to single byte `\n`s, reducing the size of the resulting text.
(Not on Windows right now, can't check.)

Comment: Windows does that, yes.  It can be used as a crafty way to get a linecount too I think

Answer (score 2):

While you're okay casting the result of `malloc` (for C++), you don't need to multiply by `sizeof(char)`, which is [always](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.6) [one](http://c-faq.com/charstring/wchar.html).

The `sizeof` function won't return the number of bytes allocated to a runtime-allocated variable (which you already keep in `fileSize`). It only works in the way you expect on statically allocated variables (e.g. `int foo[BAR]; /* sizeof(foo) returns sizeof(int)*BAR bytes */`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BAR 10

int main() {
    int foo[BAR];
    int *baz;

    fprintf(stdout, "foo: %zu\n", sizeof(foo)); /* 40 */

    baz = malloc(sizeof(int) * BAR);
    if (baz != NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "baz: %zu\n", sizeof(baz)); /* not 40, but sizeof(int*) */
        free(baz);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "could not allocate memory for baz\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

$ gcc -Wall -o test test.c
$ ./test
foo: 40
baz: 8
```

On a 64-bit system, a pointer is 8 bytes.